# How to check out a reusable workflow's repo (in GitHub actions)

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a caller workflow in repoA that triggers a reusable workflow in repoB (same org):

workflow in RepoA:

```
jobs:
  test:
    uses: myorg/repoB/.github/workflows/test.yml@master
```

workflow in RepoB:

```
name: test
on:
  workflow_call:
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: [self-hosted]
    steps:
    - name: Git checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        repository: myorg/repoB
        ref: master
        path: workflows      
    - name: Run a python script located in repoB
      run: python test.py
```

But actions/checkout fails with

```
remote: Repository not found. 
Error: fatal: repository ' https://my.enterprise.com/myorg/repoB/' not found
```

How can I checkout the reusable repo's repo in this context?
(Both repos are defined as Internal)

I tried to run a reusable workflow that executes a python script found in its repo.
But checkout of the called wowrkflow's repo failed.

Comment: Looks like an access issue within your org. Did you try cloning it without the checkout action e.g. using `git clone` command?

Comment: The reusable workflow inherits the permissions of the calling workflow, so to check out another repo than the one of the calling workflow, you have to use a PAT for `GITHUB_TOKEN`.

Answer (score 1):

The way I managed to do it using ***secrets: inherit***:

- In my Developer Settings created a PAT enabling access to repoB
- Stored the PAT value as a Repository Secret called e.g. "GH_PAT_FOR_REPO_B" in RepoA Settings/Secrets
- In calling workflow (under RepoA):

  jobs:
  test:
  uses: myorg/repoB/.github/workflows/test.yml@master
  secrets: inherit
- In reusable workflow (under RepoB):

```
    name: test
    on:
      workflow_call:
    jobs:
      test:
        runs-on: [self-hosted]
        steps:
        - name: Git checkout
          uses: actions/checkout@v3
          with:
            repository: myorg/repoB
            ref: master
            path: workflows
            token: {{ secrets.GH_PAT_FOR_REPO_B }}      
        - name: Run a python script located in repoB
          run: python test.py
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `ref:` in repoB's called action's checkout use the `@{ref}` specified in the repoA's caller's `uses: myorg/repoB/.github/workflows/test.yml@master` statement? ie: default to whatever branch is mentioned on the `uses:...` line?

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that your repository containing the reusable workflow has its access settings configured so that other repositories within your organization  can call it.

Steps to allow access:

1. On GitHub, navigate to the main page of the private repository.
2. Under your repository name, click  Settings.
3. In the left sidebar, click  Actions, then click General.
4. Under Access, choose the setting that starts with: `Accessible from repositories in the 'ORGANIZATION NAME' organization...`

Ref: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/enabling-features-for-your-repository/managing-github-actions-settings-for-a-repository#managing-access-for-a-private-repository-in-an-organization

Answer (score -1):

As it is an issue with the permissions, I'm adding the option how to resolve it with the help of GitHub app. Could be resolved also with PAM, but GitHub app is more convenient as it is not personal account dependent. It will work even if you leave the organization:)

(Tested with checkout of private repo in the organization)

Steps:

1. Under your organization [create GitHub app](https://docs.github.com/en/apps/creating-github-apps/registering-a-github-app/registering-a-github-app) with permission to read content (Repository -> Contents -> Read-only)
2. Install app and select the repository (or use it for all repositories in your org) you want to checkout from (RepoB)
3. Generate private key (in General in your GitHub app) and store it as a secret (for example with name PRIVATE_KEY) into your calling repository (RepoA)
4. Store App ID (in General in your GitHub app) as a variable (for example with name APP_ID) into your calling repository (RepoA)
5. Use actions/create-github-app-token before checkout to create a token (which will give you the permissions) like:

   ```
   - uses: actions/create-github-app-token@v1
     id: create-token
     with:
       app-id: ${{ vars.APP_ID }}
       private-key: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}
       owner: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
       repositories: repoB
   ```
6. Add generated token into the checkout actions. Like:

   ```
   - uses: actions/checkout@v4
     with:
       repository: myorg/repoB
       ref: master
       path: workflows 
       token: ${{ steps.create-token.outputs.token }}
   ```

Great YouTube resource how to create GitHub app and use it: [Working with GitHub Apps instead of a PAT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xtXnIV20XQw)

Other useful resources:

- https://docs.github.com/en/apps/creating-github-apps/about-creating-github-apps/about-creating-github-apps
- https://docs.github.com/en/apps/creating-github-apps/authenticating-with-a-github-app/making-authenticated-api-requests-with-a-github-app-in-a-github-actions-workflow
- https://github.com/actions/create-github-app-token

Comment: Instead of posting the same answer on multiple questions, please just post on one and flag the others as duplicates.